# Processing3 get "Error=2 No such file or directory" with a file that actually doesn't exist at the first place

Tags: java, ios, ffmpeg, processing, video-processing

I cannot figure it out what happen to my Processing file. I am trying to use VideoExport library and my Macbook Pro cannot play it, but the Mac-mini is able to do so.

Before the error happened it is another error=13 permission denied thing, so I messed in the terminal for a while with chmod 777 and finding the file with ls. I don't know if that may be the reason that caused this happen. FYI, I also installed ffmpeg already.

And this is the full error:

```
    java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Users/Tuang/Desktop/DMA_WORKS/Work1_Facial Muscles/Cam_Rec/sketch_161027a/sketch_161027a.pde": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at com.hamoid.VideoExport.startFfmpeg(Unknown Source)
    at com.hamoid.VideoExport.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at com.hamoid.VideoExport.saveFrame(Unknown Source)
    at Basic.draw(Basic.java:32)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2412)
    at processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT$12.callDraw(PSurfaceAWT.java:1540)
    at processing.core.PSurfaceNone$AnimationThread.run(PSurfaceNone.java:316)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 7 more
VideoExport error: Ffmpeg failed. Study /Users/Tuang/Desktop/DMA_WORKS/Work1_Facial_Muscles/Camera_Recorder/Basic/basic.mp4.txt for more details.
Could not run the sketch (Target VM failed to initialize).
For more information, read revisions.txt and Help → Troubleshooting.
```

---

1) The java.io.IOException: trying to call "/Work1_Facial Muscles/Cam_Rec/sketch_161027a/sketch_161027a.pde" which doesn't exist for real. It is gone for a long time but seems like the program stuck here.

2) "basic" is a file name from the Example of the Library. I just use it to test. Surprisingly, Every files that have been saved and changed the name still get the java.io.IOException's error of the missing sketch_161027a.pde file.

---

What I have done: 
1 I have already done the Homebrew thing to install ffmpeg.
2 I deleted everything of Processing and reinstall it again.

Any suggestion?